# Are YouTube comments upvotes/downvotes anonymous?

Tags: youtube, privacy, comments

Let's say I watched a YouTube video and notice a comment which I find interesting.
I would like to upvote the comment, but I don't want everyone to know that I watched this video.

Is there any way for anyone outside YouTube to know that I had an of interaction with this video?
For instance, could the news below pop up into someone's Google+/something feed?

> *Your friend Robert has upvoted a comment on "How to live with an incurable disease"*

*Unlike [this different question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117624/1374), this is about the **comments**.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are YouTube likes/dislikes anonymous?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117624/are-youtube-likes-dislikes-anonymous)

Comment: @LeoWattenberg: I posted these two questions because they are about different aspects of YouTube. The one you linked to is about YouTube video themselves rather than comments. It is a very different question with potentially different answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are anonymous in terms of upvote/downvote, however posting coments can be obviously tracked. Not all services are like FB.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  It would make it a much stronger answer.