# Are YouTube likes/dislikes anonymous?

Tags: youtube, privacy

Let's say I watched a YouTube video which I found interesting.
I would like to upvote it, but I don't want everyone to know that I watched it.

Is there any way for anyone outside YouTube to know that I had an of interaction with this video?
For instance, could the news below pop up into someone's Google+/something feed?

> *Your friend Robert has liked the video "How to live with an incurable disease"*

Comment: Related: [Are YouTube comments upvotes/downvotes anonymous?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117623/147505)

Comment: @sondra.kinsey: I posted these two questions because they are about different aspects of YouTube. The one you linked to is about YouTube **comments**, which is very different.

Comment: I linked to it as a related question, not as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Likes are always private and anonymous.

That said, the channel owner always can see the country of origin for likes and dislikes on videos. That information is not available for likes and dislikes on comments though.

Google+ has no relation to YouTube anymore. And is dead.

Comment: Very insightful, thanks! I just checked the link you provided, and discovered that my likes were indeed public. Is it correct to say that video likes are public by default?

Comment: There's no longer an option for keeping liked videos private on the account_privacy page. Does anyone know how privacy for these is now handled?

Comment: yes, it's now always private and can no longer be made public. I'll update the answer.